# Windows: Limit on how many regions a Window can have?

Tags: windows, winapi, window, gdi

First off all: with regions, I do not mean the region, for which that Window is for (Location on the planet), but rather the Window regions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createrectrgn

The Operating System: Windows 10
Coding Environment: C \ Win32

To change the shape of a window in Windows, one can use the [SetWindowRgn()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowrgn) function. As its second parameter, it takes a Window Region created - for example - with the CreateRectRgn from above and many more.

I am using this function to update the shape of a window up to 10 times per second.
After a few seconds of the program running the SetWindowRgn returns 0, which means that something went wrong.
My first idea was, that one of the paramter was invalid, but I keep track of their state (I check 1 line prior, if their state is valid): The Window Handle is never changed and as far as I know, will never be invalid, until as the window exists/is getting closed (which it doesn't/isn't, even after it returns 0).
The Region Handle is also not invalid, as I (1st) check if it is initialized (To combine a region with another one, the destination Region needs to exists), then (2nd) if it is NULL (which it isn't as well), and then (3rd) if it is a valid Handle (it also is). I Also use GetLastError(), to check, if an Error is set (It is not). The third parameter does not change the outcome.

I then thought, that maybe, even though the Windows Docs say:

> In particular, do not delete this region handle. The system deletes the region handle when it no longer needed.

That the Handles are not deleted, and unused handles are piling up in the memory: This is not the case (I checked with a threaded loop, that checks, wether the GetProcessHandleCount() changed or not)

Then I started timing the whole thing, to see, if there are some consistencies, some things, that allways happen before SetWindowRgn returns 0: The Time was not allways the same, but I added a variable to check how many times I use the SetWindowRgn() function: For that specific Window, I am calling this function allways exactly 4993 in Code, but I do have 2 other Windows from the same process, which all in all makes me call this Windows function 4995 times in code.
Imagining, that the CreateWindow functions call this function as well, it might be 4998 calls. After that many, SetWindowRgn() fails for that window. (I am not using it again for the other 2 windows).

The whole thing currently runs in one big thread. I am checking nearly every win32 call, to see if an error occoured (, but sometimes I wish, it would just crash instead :S ).

**TL;DR: Windows let's me use [SetWindowRgn()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowrgn) only about 5000 times**

My **Question** now is: Is this true? Is there a limit on how often one can use that function? Might it be possible, that all the other regions are cluttered on the graphics device and won't be cleaned, resulting in a memory overflow? (Perhaps somehow flushing could help..) Did I just unravel an undocumented, hardcoded limit? What can I do, to still use SetWindowRgn()?

*I appologize if some things may still be unclear and I will clarify, if you ask :), and also thank you for your time and answer!*

Comment: Check that you dispose of GDI elements after use. In windows GDI resources **are limited**. (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/gdi-objects).

Comment: You have GDI leak, maybe it's `HRGN` or maybe not. There is a limit of 10,000 gdi handles per process. Please post minimum reproducible example.

Comment: `GetProcessHandleCount()` refers to kernel handles, not GDI handles. As others have said this sounds like a GDI resource leak. You can use Task Manager (Details) pane to view the number of GDI handles used by your process.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using Regions anymore for shaping windows, that usage was deprecated when Layered Windows were introduced way back in Windows 2000. Using LWs is particularly more performant than Regions when you need to update a window's shape frequently/multiple times.

Comment: Yup, according to the details few in the task manager, it is a GDI resource leak. Once, I fixed the leak, I will answer my question etc... Thanks again :) ...

I could not find a way to use Layerd Windows as themselves to make oddly shaped windows though. If I am going to find a way, I will make sure to use them.

Comment: Layered windows need alpha blending, for example using gdi+, otherwise they have the same rough edges.

Comment: I read up a little on the layered windows and there are some things, that make me believe, that my way is more usefull to me: first of all, to make windows look oddly shaped I will have to specify WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, correct? The docs for this extended style https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles even reference the SetWindowRgn() function. Then: I don't really care about the rough edges, but I guess it would improve my application. Third:If I understand correctly I would need to implement my own code to test if the cursor is inside the windowrgn or outside.

Comment: Unless I find a way to make the last one more easy, using the windows api, I think I might stick with SetWindowRgn(). I am not willing to waste more hours on this project. I am still thankful for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments under the question suggest correctly: The issue was a GDI resource leak. I noticed this after checking the details few in the task manager. As Barmark Shemirani commented: The SetWindowRgn() started to fail after exactly 10000 GDI Objects.
Checking all the possible objects on the [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/gdi-objects) was trivial to pinpoint the leak.

The issue in the Code was: I forgot to delete 2 results of different CombineRgn() functions. Now, that I added 2 DeleteObject() funtion calls, everything works fine now.

The Credits for pointing out the issue go to the commenters! :)